# Not able to get from date

Tags: php, mysql

if i enter two different values i am getting the date to_date value in from_date value

```
$to_date=$_POST['date'];
$from_date=$_POST['date'];
$query="SELECT * FROM reports WHERE date BETWEEN $from_date AND $to_date";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
$qty= 0;
while ($num = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query_run)) {
    $qty += $num['amount'];
}
echo $qty;
```

what is the right way to do

Comment: SELECT SUM(amount) as sum FROM ....

Comment: something like `"SELECT * FROM reports WHERE date BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date'";` missing quotes

Comment: 1. Don't use the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Since you set both `$to_date` and `$from_date` to `$_POST['date']` (the same value), it doesn't make any sense to use `BETWEEN`. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: you can try `$query="SELECT SUM(amount) as total_amount FROM reports WHERE date BETWEEN $from_date AND $to_date"`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`, because `mysql_*` is deprecated and closed in PHP 7.

In your code you need to use quotes around `$from_date` and `$to_date`.

One more thing, if your start and end date is same than don't know why are you using BETWEEN, you can just simply use `=`.

**Here is the complete example of your code by using [MYSQLi Object Oriented](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$to_date = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['date']);
//$from_date = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['date']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE date = '$to_date'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$qty = 0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $qty += $row['amount'];
    }
    echo $qty;
} 
else 
{
    echo "No record found";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Also note that, if this query is just for getting total amount no other use, than you can use your query like:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM reports WHERE date = '$to_date'
```

**Update:**

As per Mr. Magnus suggested, here is the basic example of Prepared Statements.

> [From the Manual:](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) The user input is automatically quoted, so there
>   is no risk of a SQL injection attack.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE date = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
if ($stmt->execute(array($_POST['date']))) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // your stuff
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is a good answer. The only thing I would change is for it to use prepared statements instead of concatenating the query string. Escaping strings doesn't 100% secure you from injections. Prepared statements does.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: agreed with you, 100%,